# How to use Fetch API for GET request

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to `GET` JSON from the endpoint https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/brawlers.

(https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/brawlers?Authorization="Bearer%20[My API Key]")

Here's my Code:

```js
let url = 'https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/brawlers'
    fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer **USER'S API KEY GOES HERE**"
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        let json = response.json();
        console.log(json);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
    });
```

This is the output (error):

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/brawlers' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8887' has been
> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If
> an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS
> disabled.
> sketch.js:3 GET https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/brawlers net::ERR_FAILED
> 127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe

Comment: [Will it CORS?](https://httptoolkit.tech/will-it-cors/)

Answer (score 0):

In your header, you need to enable CORS like CBroe said :

```
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8887');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

Edit :

The server (that the POST request is sent to) needs to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header (etc) in its response. Putting them in your request from the client has no effect.

This is because it is up to the server to specify that it accepts cross-origin requests (and that it permits the Content-Type request header, and so on) – the client cannot decide for itself that a given server should allow CORS.

Comment: Ok, I did that and now it says 
Access to fetch at 'https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/brawlers' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8887' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
OOPS